# CSS design to show alternate color for rows of data by group ID

Tags: php, html, css

I have created a web application that shows a list of data from the database that shows like this

[image]

Instead of the same color for each row of data. I like the CSS to able to show different alternate colors for rows of data by group ID which look like below. How can i achieve that?

[image]

This is my CSS code:

```
.datarows{
    background-color: #00BFFF;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:2px;    
}

.datarows a{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: 0.9em arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.datarows .tripid{
    background-color: #000080;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px;
}

.datarows .time{
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFA500;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px;
}

.datarows a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
}
```

PHP and HTML code for generating the rows of data

```
<?php       
   $curdate = date("Y-m-d");

    $query_curdate = "SELECT a.trip_id, b.start_time, b.end_time, c.activity_name FROM TRIP a JOIN ACTIVITY b ON a.trip_no = b.trip_no 
                          JOIN ACTIVITY_TYPE c ON b.activity_id = c.activity_id WHERE a.trip_date = ?";
        $params_curdate = array($curdate);
        $stmt_curdate = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_curdate, $params_curdate);

                                while( $row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt_1curdate, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {

                                    $tripid_1 = $row1[0];
                                    $starttime_1 = $row1[1]->format('h:i');
                                    $endtime_1 = $row1[2]->format('h:i');
                                    $activitytype_1 = $row1[3];
                                ?>

                                <div class="datarows"><a href="">
                                <div class="tripid"><?php echo $tripid_1; ?></div> 
                                <div class="time"><?php echo $starttime_1." - ".$endtime_1; ?></div>
                                <?php echo $activitytype_1."<br/><br/>"; ?>
                                </a></div>

                                <?php               
                                }
                                ?>
```

Comment: It would be better if you just post the generated HTML instead of PHP.

Comment: it should be easier if you have the data grouped initially, then present it in html

Comment: @Ghost The problem is i'm not using aggregate function for my sql query so i can't use group by

Comment: @LesYun what I mean, to clarify is after fetching the data, you need a grouped array, meaning you group them by `trip_id` in the an array (and im assuming that `trip_id` is unique), so that you know structurally which row belongs to, from that you can put one group into one `div`, the rest is just css

Comment: Are they grouped in threes, and what are the group ID's?

Comment: _“The problem is i'm not using aggregate function for my sql query so i can't use group by”_ - GROUP BY would not be the right thing to use for this anyway - that _reduces_ the set of records that fulfill the same criterion to a _single_ record, and that is not what you want here in the first place. What you actually want, is to just implement a simple, single-level [control break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break) in your loop that outputs the data.

Answer (score 2):

Like what I have said in the comments above, alternatively, you can group the array first before presenting, so that you know which row belong to what group.

In this case, just use and group them via `trip_id`:

```
$grouped_trips = array(); // initialize container
while ($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_1curdate, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
    $tripid_1 = $row1[0];
    $starttime_1 = $row1[1]->format('h:i');
    $endtime_1 = $row1[2]->format('h:i');
    $activitytype_1 = $row1[3];
    // push them inside
    $grouped_trips[$tripid_1][] = array(
        'trip_id' => $tripid_1,
        'start_time' => $starttime_1,
        'end_time' => $endtime_1,
        'activity_type' => $activitytype_1
    );
}
```

Basically what this line does is push all the batches in the same group:

```
$grouped_trips[$tripid][]
                // ^
```

So this should yield something in this fashion:

```
Array (
    [35KH1] => Array (
        [0] => Array(
            [trip_id] => 35KH3
            [start_time] => 06:00
            [end_time] => 06:10
            [activity_type] => (D) NORMAL DREDGING
        )

        [1] => Array(
            [trip_id] => 35KH3
            [start_time] => 06:10
            [end_time] => 06:15
            [activity_type] => (M) SHIFTING / REPOSITIONING
        )
    )

    [35KH4] => Array (
        [0] => Array(
            [trip_id] => 35KH4
            [start_time] => 06:45
            [end_time] => 07:10
            [activity_type] => (D) NORMAL DREDGING
        )

        [1] => Array(
            [trip_id] => 35KH4
            [start_time] => 07:10
            [end_time] => 08:00
            [activity_type] => (M) SHIFTING / REPOSITIONING
        )
    )
)
```

Now you have a clear and grouped structure. After that its just a matter of presenting it:

Here's the full code and try to fit it in:

```
<?php

$curdate = date('Y-m-d');
$query_curdate = "
    SELECT a.trip_id, b.start_time, b.end_time, c.activity_name 
        FROM TRIP a 
        JOIN ACTIVITY b ON a.trip_no = b.trip_no 
        JOIN ACTIVITY_TYPE c ON b.activity_id = c.activity_id 
    WHERE a.trip_date = ?
";
$params_curdate = array($curdate);
$stmt_curdate = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query_curdate, $params_curdate);

$grouped_trips = array();
while ($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_1curdate, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
    $tripid_1 = $row1[0];
    $starttime_1 = $row1[1]->format('h:i');
    $endtime_1 = $row1[2]->format('h:i');
    $activitytype_1 = $row1[3];

    $grouped_trips[$tripid_1][] = array(
        'trip_id' => $tripid_1,
        'start_time' => $starttime_1,
        'end_time' => $endtime_1,
        'activity_type' => $activitytype_1
    );
}
?>

<?php foreach ($grouped_trips as $trip_id => $groups): ?>
<div class="group"> <!-- add your CSS to each 35KH# group -->
    <div class="tripid"><?php echo $trip_id; ?></div> 
    <?php foreach ($groups as $group): ?>
    <div class="datarows">
        <a href="#" title="">
            <div class="time">
                <span><?php echo $group['start_time']; ?></span>
                <span> - </span>
                <span><?php echo $group['end_time']; ?></span>
            </div>
            <span><?php echo $group['activity_type']; ?></span>
            <br/><br/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now for the CSS, its up to your imagination on how to design it. You can add a little bit of:

```
.group:nth-child(odd){
    background:#ccc;
}
.group:nth-child(even){
    background:#222;
}
```

Just mix and match some of the codes above since I can't test it all. But you get the idea. This should put you in the track.